# Django inline formset for each object delete

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

```
if formset.is_valid():
  values = formset.save(commit=False)
    for v in values:
      v.correct = True
      v.save()
```

How can I delete objects where delete is checked? Thanks

Comment: This is [covered in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, in your formset, mark your delete checkboxes with `name="form-0-DELETE"`, `name="form-1-DELETE"`, etc.

Then in your `if form.is_valid and formset.is_valid` iterate over the values marked for delete.

```
for delete_value in formset.deleted_objects:
    delete_value.delete()
```

Then continue with saving your formset

Comment: don't provide commit=False